# C++20 Hashing And Searching

Tags: c++, c++20

Imagine we have a custom struct Pixel2D. Can we 1. store pixels in an unordered_set 2. search in the  set by two integers?

If we want to store pixels in an unordered_set and be able to search by a temporary object, then we can have the below:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Pixel2DWithCount {
  int x, y;
  Pixel2DWithCount(int x_, int y_): x(x_), y(y_){}
  // comparison operator is not a class function. It's here for a more compact view
  inline friend bool operator==(const Pixel2DWithCount &first, const Pixel2DWithCount &second) noexcept{
        return first.x == second.x && first.y == second.y;
    }
};

struct Pixel2DWithCountHasher {
  std::hash<long> _hasher;
  size_t operator()(const Pixel2DWithCount& p) const {
    // shifting 4 bytes
    constexpr size_t _shift_bits_num = sizeof(int) * 8;
    return _hasher(static_cast<long>(p.x) << _shift_bits_num |
                  static_cast<long>(p.y));
  }
};

int main(){
    Pixel2DWithCount p1(1, 2);
    Pixel2DWithCount p2(2, 2);
    std::unordered_set<Pixel2DWithCount, Pixel2DWithCountHasher> s{p1, p2};
    std::cout<<(s.find(p1) != s.end());
}
```

**Pre C++20**: above is the only bet: searching by temporary objects. The drawback of course, is the overhead from temporary object creations. Ideally, we want to be able to search by the x and y values. That means having a  hashing(Pixel2DWithCount)->x,y function.

**C++20**: transparent hashing is meant to allow hashing with related types. So searching by x and values sounds possible.

```
struct ComparePixel2DWithCount{
    // This functor is necessary
    bool operator()(const Pixel2DWithCount &first, const Pixel2DWithCount &second) const noexcept{
        return first.x == second.x && first.y == second.y;
    }
    // This is key to transparent
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int, int> &first, const Pixel2DWithCount &second) const noexcept{
        return first.first == second.x && first.second == second.y;
    }

    bool operator()(const Pixel2DWithCount &first, const std::pair<int, int> &second) const noexcept{
        return first.x == second.first && first.y == second.second;
    }
};

struct Pixel2DWithCountHasher {
  std::hash<long> _hasher;
  // hwy this function cannot call the other ()?
  size_t operator()(const std::pair<int, int>& pair) const {
    // shifting 4 bytes
    constexpr size_t _shift_bits_num = sizeof(int) * 8;
    return _hasher(static_cast<long>(pair.first) << _shift_bits_num | 
    static_cast<long>(pair.second));
  }
   size_t operator()(const Pixel2DWithCount& p) const {
    // shifting 4 bytes
    constexpr size_t _shift_bits_num = sizeof(int) * 8;
    return _hasher(static_cast<long>(p.x) << _shift_bits_num |
                   static_cast<long>(p.y));
   }
};

int main(){
  // this is what seems to be the set up of transparent hashing
  std::unordered_set<Pixel2DWithCount, 
                     Pixel2DWithCountHasher, 
                     ComparePixel2DWithCount> s{p1, p2};
}
```

However, using the above construct, the compiler still suffers from error: no matching function for call to std::unordered_set<Pixel2DWithCount, Pixel2DWithCountHasher, ComparePixel2DWithCount>::find(std::pair<int, int>)' 
Why?

Comment: You need to define your hasher and your comparator both having `is_transparent` typedef member. See [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find).

Comment: `std::unordered_set::find` still only takes one parameter, so you still need to pack your `x` and `y` into some object.  At least in the example shown, `Pixel2DWithCount` doesn't seem more expensive to construct than `std::pair<int, int>`, so you are likely not gaining anything.

Answer (score 2):

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find),

> 3,4) Finds an element with key that compares equivalent to the value x. This overload participates in overload resolution only if Hash::is_transparent and KeyEqual::is_transparent are valid and each denotes a type. This assumes that such Hash is callable with both K and Key type, and that the KeyEqual is transparent, which, together, allows calling this function without constructing an instance of Key.

Add `is_transparent` in your `Pixel2DWithCountHasher` and `ComparePixel2DWithCount` is the solution,

```cpp
struct Pixel2DWithCountHasher {
  using is_transparent = void;
};

struct ComparePixel2DWithCount {
  using is_transparent = void;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EWeTz65x8)

P.S. I believe your case might not be well-suited for transparent hashing unless your real-world scenario is much more complicated. The cost of constructing a `Pixel2DWithCount` object is comparable to, if not less than, that of a `std::pair<int, int>`, given it merely consists of two integers.